# Some post-upgrade changes not executed?

Tags: upgrade, indicator, libraries, clock

Today I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS via `do-release-upgrade` and the upgrade went fine except my computer hung up and I restarted it using the power button (EDIT: I think I did a proper reboot after the OS upgrade, so that the power button reboot wasn't the first reboot after the upgrade). After the reboot there were some disk errors and initramfs requested me to run `fsck` so I did and the system booted but the clock indicator applet didn't load.

I noticed that the .so file of a library the clock uses (libsecret-1.0-0) file was missing even though the package was installed. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsecret-1.0-0` helped.

Then I tried running gedit and same thing, but this time another library was missing.

In general the system works, you wouldn't even know something's wrong, but it is possible that some other libraries are missing and I'd rather fix it now than deal with errors every now and then in the future. Is it possible that some post-upgrade post-reboot hooks didn't run because my reboot wasn't "clean" or something like that? Why are some of the libs not configured?

All the best.

Comment: Try *sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade* and watch for errors.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thanks for the reply. No errors.